# Serving Fonts to multiple Subdomains Issue

Tags: css, .htaccess, fonts, font-face

I am currently attempting to create a font library which can be accessed by my various domains.

I have heavily researched the problem and it appears that the issue stems from 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' having to be setup correctly in my .htaccess file.

Having tried multiple times I simply cannot solve the issue.

**I have set it up as follows:**

In the root of my server I have created a .htaccess file.This file contains

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(eot|font.css|otf|ttc|ttf|woff|woff2)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
# Web fonts
AddType application/font-woff woff
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject eot
```

Within the root folder on my server are then contained the folders containing my various domains.As so:

```
-ROOT Folder
     |
     -.htaccess
     -Fonts Folder (which contains the relevant font files to serve)
     -Domain 1 Root Folder
     -Domain 2 Root Folder
     -Domain 3 Root Folder
     -Domain 4 Root Folder
```

I'm sure that I am in some way being completely inept and doing something very fundamentally wrong,but right now I just can't see it, so any help with this issue would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are in the right way... but to be sure, check in Chrome console (for example), when u visit from other than main domain - did u get some error or notification about it. Maybe is something with htaccess, or wrong paths... But we need a track it. Make sure the .htaccess file is in folder with shared libraries/fonts.

Amm, just to be sure, i will paste mine htaccess part of project that worked with this kind of library usage (in my case, i give permission only for those domains):

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(www\.)?(domain1.t.com|dom2.t.com|dom3.t.com|dom4.t.com)$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0$1
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
</ifModule>
```

Or just

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
</ifModule>
```

Good luck there.

Comment: Many thanks Boris.I will look into this now.One thing which sprang to mind though is that you state that the .htaccess file should be in the folder where the foots are.....currently the .htaccess is in the ROOT and the the FONTS folder is in the Root.Should I move the .htaccess into the FONTS folder?

Comment: Its good to try. In any case you didnt need all files to be served for unwanted (all internet) domains. So try... And do not forget to see what information console gives you about transferred files (network part). 
Give a reply when u did it :) Good luck!

Comment: Boris,I have seen the light and thankyou very much for making me see it!Although the answer was very simple...a simple typo error in code where every font had .eot before it's file name!!!! e.g eot.woff.Crazy!Your first code works perfectly,and is exactly what I'm looking for as I want to restrict access purely to my own domains.Thanks very much for your input,as I say it is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just to confirm for anyone else having this issue,I can confirm it is solved by doing the following.

1) Create a .htaccess file

2) Insert the following code into the .htaccess file:

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(www\.)?(domain1.t.com|dom2.t.com|dom3.t.com|dom4.t.com)$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0$1
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
```

3) Enter the domains you want to allow access to in the above code

(domain1.t.com|dom2.t.com|dom3.t.com|dom4.t.com)

should become:

(mydomain.com|mydomain2.com|mydomain3.com|mydomain4.com)

where 'mydomain.com' is the domain you are giving access to

4) Place file in the top level ROOT directory of your server

The domains you listed should now be able to access your font's when linked to correctly.